# mysql query getting different results in mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm getting different results with what I understand to be the same query from two different interfaces. The first is a mysql shell:

```
mysql> select * from table where sub_date > '2012-11-08' order by sub_date asc limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 id: **176041922**
```

The second is a little function I put together to test a query that would pull a certain amount of records based on the datetime field "sub_date":

```
>>> r_query('>', '2012-11-08', '1')
((**18393664L**, 3, .....)
```

Here's the python module:

```
import MySQLdb
myuser = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='myuser', passwd='mypass', db='mydatabase')
cur = myuser.cursor()

def r_query(oper, date, limit):
    cur.execute("""select * from table where sub_date %s %s order by sub_date asc limit %s""" % (oper, date, limit)) 
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print result
```

Comment: @Travesty3 Make that an answer and I'll vote for it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nearly nothing about python. But I'm pretty sure you need to put extra quotes around your date parameter in order for it to be quoted in the query string. Probably more like:

```
cur.execute("""select * from table where sub_date %s '%s' order by sub_date asc limit %s""" % (oper, date, limit))
```

(note the extra quotes around the second %s).

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for the quick and easy answer.

Comment: No prob. Gotta love it when it's a simple fix :-)